# Why don't Wolverine's claws grow back with Adamantium?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

So I am re-watching The Wolverine and it seems quite conflicting. I thought because ALL bone was basically Adamantium now that there wouldn't be plain bone claws. If there was still bone claws wouldn't he have Adamantium bone claws? But also since the original blade claws were his claws, wouldn't he regrow them because of his regeneration and that his bones were basically Adamantium after the Weapon X thing?

Answer (score 6):

My understanding was that claws were just bones. He had the Adamantium put on his bones, as in they covered them. Once he had his claws broken off, the Adamantium came with them, and the original bone is what regrew. Weapon X didn't give him Adamantium bones, they just covered them in Adamantium. He still has bone underneath, and that bone is weak, like any humans.

Comment: Related --> http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12609/25784